# How to join with multiple tables of this complicated case?

Tags: sql, join

I have 4 tables with the following relationship. Table_3 is the central table of the star schema. How to write a sql to join these 4 tables ? The difficult thing is how to join table_1 with table_2 ? Do I have to use sub-query (nested join ) ?

```
table_1 <-- table_2 <-- table_3 --> table_4
```

Comment: If it's really a star than join center to all ends.

Comment: what is the table structure ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For star schema you should join each table exactly with central table. 

Should be something like:

```
select *
from table_3 central
join table_1 t1 on central.id = t1.central_id
join table_2 t2 on central.id = t2.central_id
join table_4 t4 on central.id = t4.central_id
;
```

For case when table_1 - out of star scheme.

```
select *
from table_3 central
join table_2 t2 on central.id = t2.central_id
join table_4 t4 on central.id = t4.central_id
join table_1 t1 on t2.id = t1.table_2_id
;
```

Comment: What I'd like to do is to join table_3 with table_2 and table_4, and also join table_2 with table_1

Comment: In this case, your table table_1 - not in star scheme. I've added new example.

Comment: Awesome! I'm so glad!)

Answer (score 0):

Following the linkage shown by you
table_1 <-- table_2 <-- table_3 --> table_4

below query should get the needed data:

```
Select * from table_3 t3
join table_4 t4 on t3.IdOftable_4 = t4.Id
join table_2 t2 on t3.IdOftable_2 = t2.Id
join table_1 t1 on t2.IdOftable_1 = t1.Id
```